# How to develop iPhone app for iPhone 5 and newer?

Tags: ios, iphone

We are developing an application, targeting iPhones, starting from 5 and all the newer models.

Recently, I discovered there is no way to say, that app does not support iPhone 4s.

My ideas are:

- Just don't think about 4s. Whatever it looks there...
- Give a message in application, that it does not work on 4s.

Questions are:

1. Are there any other options I have?
2. Is it a risk of not getting into App Store?

Comment: As Duncan C mention it is mandatory support iPhone 4s for iOS<10. Your app will definitely be rejected from AppStore.

Comment: No it's not. A lot of apps have "App doesn't work on iPhone 4s" in their description, so there is a way to do that. Of course you can add Metal or something, but this way iPhone 5 will be out too..

Comment: Just be aware that you app also has to run on the iPad (in iPhone mode) and this uses the 3.5" version of your app. Thus if you plan to drop the iPhone 4S because of the screen size you will run into difficulties in review if they test you app on an iPad. (this has happend).

Answer (score 0):

iOS 10 will not support the 4s. If you target your app for iOS 10 and later you can skip the 4s.

Aside from that you'll need some hardware feature that the 4s lacks that all subsequent models have, and make your app require that feature.

(I don't think Apple allows you to pick and choose the models you support.)

Answer (score 0):

Build only for iPhone 5+ architecture armv7s & arm64
Might be one solution.

[iPhone_architecture image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5s5W.png)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using xCode 8, and iOS 10 that not support iPhone 4s.